# How to use JavaScript to hide <h1> and <p> tag in a webpage?

Tags: javascript

If there are a bunch of H1 and P tags in my document and there is no ID associated with them, how do I target particular P and H1 tags using JavaScript? I have no control over the creation of the page; thus, I'm resorting to using JavaScript to manipulate on the client side.

Comment: With `document.getElementsByTagName("p");` you can get all paragraphs.

Comment: You could use classes, the DOM hierarchy, element attributes, etc. You should post the code you're working with and an example of what you've tried.

Comment: You can use CSS selectors even if there is no ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName('p');

for (var i = 0, l = ps.length; i < l; i++) {
    ps[i].setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
}
```

Repeat for h1 tags.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a sad place to be, but if you've no access, you'll want to use something like:

```
var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = pTags.length; i--;) {
    var self = pTags[i];
    self.style.display = 'none';
}
```

This however will hide all of them, so you'll want to filter out the ones you do have. And the same for your H1 tags. Not an ideal solution as you'll likely run into further issues.

You mention that some do not have ID attributes, you could filter those out:

```
var pTags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = pTags.length; i--;) {
    var self = pTags[i];
    if (!self.hasAttribute('id')) {
        self.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for all the help. Why is the following line of code not working?

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].style.display = 'none'

I tried this for the h1 and it works fine.

document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].style.display = 'none'

Answer (score 0):

1. By Order
2. By Value
3. By constellation (So you know there is a img bevor the h1 or something else)